# write file not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having trouble with one of my codeigniter function write_file(), for some reason will write to two other files but not the one on the application path.

I am stumbled on that will not write to application database when add migrations.

**Does Not Write to File**

```
write_file(APPPATH . 'config/database.php', $get_template_file_contents, 'r+');
```

**Controller**

```
public function index() {

unset($this->db);

$dsn = $this->input->post('db_driver').$this->input->post('db_username').':'. $this->input->post('db_password').'@'.$this->input->post('db_hostname').'/'.$this->input->post('db_database');

if (is_resource($this->db->conn_id) OR is_object($this->db->conn_id)) {

$data = array();
$data['db_hostname'] = $this->input->post('db_hostname');
$data['db_username'] = $this->input->post('db_username');
$data['db_password'] = $this->input->post('db_password');
$data['db_database'] = $this->input->post('db_database');
$data['db_driver'] = $this->input->post('db_driver');
$data['db_prefix'] = $this->input->post('db_prefix');

$get_template_file_contents  = $this->load->view('template/configuration/database.php', $data, true);

// Does Not Write to File
write_file(APPPATH . 'config/database.php', $get_template_file_contents, 'r+');

// Writes to files OK
write_file(dirname(FCPATH) . '/admin/application/config/database.php', $get_template_file_contents, 'r+');
write_file(dirname(FCPATH) . '/catalog/config/database.php', $get_template_file_contents, 'r+');

$this->load->library('migration');
$this->migration->version(1);
redirect('step_5');

} else {


redirect(step_3);

}

}
```

Comment: Note: In order for write_file function to write data to a file its file permissions must be set such that it is writable (666, 777, etc.). If the file does not already exist, the directory containing it must be writable.

Comment: But writes to the other location OK And have not set any permission. Just first write file not work since put migrations on there.

Comment: at previous location you might be having more read/write access on the folder, check that might solve your problem ? or may be path issue of that file folder

Answer (score 0):

I had to change couple things around but now after testing all good now.

```
$data['db_hostname']    = $this->input->post('db_hostname');
$data['db_username']    = $this->input->post('db_username');
$data['db_password']    = $this->input->post('db_password');
$data['db_database']    = $this->input->post('db_database');
$data['db_driver']  = $this->input->post('db_driver');
$data['db_prefix']  = $this->input->post('db_prefix');

$get_template_file_contents  = $this->load->view('template/configuration/database', $data, true);
write_file(dirname(FCPATH) . '/admin/application/config/database.php', $get_template_file_contents, 'r+');
write_file(dirname(FCPATH) . '/catalog/config/database.php', $get_template_file_contents, 'r+');
write_file(FCPATH . '/application/config/database.php', $get_template_file_contents, 'r+');


if(write_file(FCPATH . '/application/config/database.php', $get_template_file_contents, 'r+') == true) {

// To Do Fix Load Method Will Not Load On Form Submit.
// Due To Migrations Loading First Before Database.

$this->load->library('migration');
$this->migration->version(1);
redirect('step_5');

} else {
redirect('step_3');
}
```